# Xcode stuck compiling

Tags: xcode4.3

I've got an Xcode project that gets stuck compiling one source file, and I don't know how to fix this or how to find out which file it is compiling.

I have Xcode 4.3.2

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

One reason for this could be circular #include...

This is a beginner tip, but I think it is worth mentioning just in case in can help you or others.

If you are including header files using #include, make you have something to prevent circular header such as

```
#ifndef MY_FILE_INCLUDED
#define MY_FILE_INCLUDED
    <your header file>
#endif
```

If you are using #import, the compiler takes care of removing circular header, each header file is only included once.

Also, you can try commenting part of your code to make your file as minimal as possible. You can remove method implementations and most of the code and add it method by method to see if it makes the problem more obvious.

And to find which file it is compiling, you can see the compile log, last icon on the right, it looks like a bubble with lines inside. Click on the compilation log that is active (has a spinner beside it), you should see which files have already been compiled and which is currently compiling.

Comment: It wasn't this,but it was not a bad ideea.Apparently it gets stuck in a .mm